# linux kernel driver- synchronize between irq and a worker thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, serial-port, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a scenario in serial Linux driver

Point 1:
IRQ call serial driver receives set of bytes continuously based on request made by linux user space , and a we get a set of serial bytes (Frame1) from other nodes,

Point 2:
we need to check time stamp of each byte with some time say t1 secs, if a received bytes exceeds t1 sec , the driver treat as a next frame(Frame 2) to process,

how do we achieve Point 2 in a linux driver ?,
i was thinking of create a worker thread, but i am not sure to validate point 2.

there could be chance that IRQ can validate Frame check using the same t1 secs.

Please help whats the best kernel function call i can use to fit this scenario.

Comment: Linux is not a RTOS. You need an additional micro controller for that. UART requires too much work even on modern SoCs.

Comment: agreed but still we need to make it work on Linux, i tried to acheive point 2 using ioctl, which our user space call, some time i see there is a miss in identifying frames

so i thought there would be easy way to handling using worker thread or any thing else

Comment: @0andriy.....uh?  UART too much work?  Even the hopeless 8051 has a UART.  Both Windows and Linux have UART drivers that work fine.

Comment: 'protocols' based on timing are notoriously unreliable.. Can you not design your system with a real protocol?

Comment: no not possible, say 9600B(baud) has every byte interval time gap time is 1.04166 ms or 1042 usec so a fuction is expected to call every 521 us like a polling function call, is that possible ?

Comment: i have a hint of working with worker thread.. but not sure how will it goes, so is this right way to do it .. or any better solution

Comment: @MartinJames Sadly, there are protocols that rely on such timings, such as Modbus RTU.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you polling a free-running timer in your UART interrupt-handler, comparing against the previous value, making a decision and then updating the previous value.  When you have assembled a protocol unit, you could queue it off and signal a semaphore to notify some thread that a PU is available in the queue.

Comment: A byte-by-byte state-machine in the interrupt-handler or driver callback is a better solution than trying to signal off individual bytes with time-stamps to a thread.

Comment: You need a timer with enough granularity to run your protocol.  TBH, 9600 baud is so slow that almost anything would work, (well, maybe not ruby:)

Comment: You cannot do this with Linux software.  The random interrupt latency will make timer measurements inaccurate.  The solution is to use proper hardware, i.e. a U[S]ART that has a 'receiver timeout' capability that monitors the serial input.  After a character has been received and the line is then idle for a set time, an interrupt is generated.

Comment: @MartinJames, haha, It's unbelievable that people do not understand the problems with UART in modern General Purpose OSes. Since UART has neither big FIFO, nor some better hardware level overflow protocol protection it consumes a lot of CPU power in case to achive low latency. Basically you have to convert costful core of SMP system to a microcontroller that will do this for you. I proposed cheapest way: external $2 microcontroller which do what OP wants quite reliably.

Comment: To OP. If you really wish to go hard way, you need approx. the following: a) apply RT patch on top of kernel; b) pin one CPU core to handle UART IRQ (no other handlers must be there!); c) either modify UART driver, or create a user space application which also be pinned to the same CPU (other tasks should be forbiden to migrate from or to that CPU!); d) disable any power management on this core (PM QoS). This will do something close to what you want.

Comment: @0andriy ....9600 baud.... 'low latency' is an inappropriate term:)

Comment: @0andriy all UART since perhistory hava a 16-byte FIFO.  That is 16ms at 9600 baud.  Put another way, that is forever for a modern CPU.

Comment: I mean, bog-standard Windows drivers work reliably at 256k without any hardware shenanigans.  9600?  You could do it with an abacus, providing it has an interrupt driver:)

Comment: 'A lot of CPU power'?  It's barely measurable.

Comment: @MartinJames *"all UART since perhistory hava a 16-byte FIFO"* -- That's a ridiculous and false statement.  Besides, the use of a receive FIFO would obliterate any/all timing information that was on the wire.  Seems like you don't understand the OP's actual problem, who is asking a XY question.

Comment: *"we need to check time stamp of each byte ..."* -- Even if you could accurately timestamp each byte (which is doubtful by software or hardware), the proposed algorithm is flawed because it creates a ***rotting packet*** situation. When a packet is received, it is not actually identified as a complete packet until the next byte is received after an idle time (i.e. first byte of next packet). But if the line actually goes idle for a longer time (i.e. nobody sends anything), then that received packet is stalled and not forwarded for processing.

Comment: i need in solution in linux, i able to work perfectly in RTOS environment, has any one idea is it  better to handle using worker thread (Deferred work)

Comment: @sawdust 1987: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART

Comment: The 16550 was so all-pervasive that all the embedded on-chip UARTs I've seen are compatible with it.

Comment: @0andriy please.... 'low latency' and '9600 baud' should not appear in the same post:(